# Guardar e enviar id de item selecionado no dropdowlinst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer uma busca, filtrando através de um dropdowlist. Em resumo, eu seleciono um nível de instrução numa lista e ao clicar em 'Buscar' quero retornar a lista de pessoas que possuem aquele nível de escolaridade. 
Meu problema está na identificação do item selecionado no dropdownlist. Se eu selecionar qualquer coisa a busca não me retorna nada. Mas se eu passo um valor para o id como no exemplo abaixo, ao clicar em Buscar recebo como retorno todas as pessoas que possuem aquele nível igual ao id informado. O que preciso pra fazer pra pegar o id do item selecionado?

**Meu Controller**

```
public class FormacaoController : Controller
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.NívelId = new SelectList(db.Escolaridades, "Id", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pesquisa(int id = 3) // 'setando' um valor, ao clicar em buscar, retorna as informaçãos. Se não passar um valor aqui para o id, a consulta não retorna nada.
    {
        var resultado = db.Cursos.Include(c => c.Perfil).Where(c => c.NívelId == id);
        ViewBag.Perfil = db.Perfis.AsEnumerable();
        ViewBag.NívelId = new SelectList(db.Escolaridades, "Id", "Nome");

        return View(resultado);
    }
    }
```

**View Index**

```
    <div> 
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Formacao", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil> modelPerfil = (IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil>)ViewBag.Perfil;

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.DropDownList("NívelId")

     </div> 

     <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
 }
```

**View Pesquisa**

```
<div> 
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Formacao"))
 {
     IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil> modelPerfil = (IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil>)ViewBag.Perfil;
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.DropDownList("NívelId")

     </div> 

     <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
 }
```

```
   <table>

    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
        <th>Nome <b>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></th>


    </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td width="30%">@item.Nome></td> 
                    <td width="30%">@item.Instituição</td> 
                    <td width="30%">@item.Perfil.Nome</td> 
                </tr>
                }
            }
        }
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

## Método do Cigano de Como Implementar um Formulário de Pesquisa

Este é o método que uso nas minhas aplicações, e tem várias vantagens:

- Parâmetros de pesquisa na URL. Não é preciso um `form` para repetir a pesquisa. Um simples F5 ou [Ctrl/Command] + R já faz isso;
- Amigável pra SEO;
- Parâmetros de pesquisa vêm preenchidos no formulário de pesquisa;
- Formulário de pesquisa pode aparecer em qualquer tela.

### 1. O formulário de pesquisa precisa ter `FormMethod.GET`

Se é pesquisa, os parâmetros devem ficar no endereço da requisição, para que você possa chamar facilmente a pesquisa sem precisar de um formulário.

Para isso, faça uma *Partial* com o seguinte:

#### `_Pesquisa.cshtml`

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Formacao", FormMethod.GET))
 {
     IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil> modelPerfil = (IEnumerable<MinhaBase.Models.Perfil>)ViewBag.Perfil;

     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.DropDownList("NivelId")
     </div> 

     <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
 }
```

### 2. O formulário de pesquisa deve ser uma *Partial*

Isto porque possivelmente ele vai aparecer em N Views do seu código.

### 3. Crie uma *ViewModel* que contenha os parâmetros de pesquisa e o resultado dela

Ou seja:

```
public class PesquisaViewModel
{
    public int NivelId { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

### 4. O *Controller* deve aceitar o *ViewModel* na pesquisa

Ele pode aceitar `POST` também, mas a meu ver não precisa.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Pesquisa(PesquisaViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel != null) 
    {
        viewModel.Cursos = db.Cursos.Include(c => c.Perfil).Where(c => c.NivelId == viewModel.NivelId);
    }

    ViewBag.Perfil = db.Perfis;
    ViewBag.Niveis = db.Escolaridades;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

### 5. `_Pesquisa` e a *View* de resultado da pesquisa devem ser tipadas pelo *ViewModel*

#### `_Pesquisa.cshtml`

```
 @model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.PesquisaViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Formacao", FormMethod.GET))
 {
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NivelId, ((IEnumerable<Escolaridade>)ViewBag.Niveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem 
         {
             Text = option.Nome,
             Value = option.NivelId.ToString(),
             Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.NivelId == option.NivelId)
         }), "Selecione...")
     </div> 

     <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
 }
```

#### `Pesquisa.cshtml`

Se o nome ficar ambíguo, use `ResultadoPesquisa.cshtml`.

```
 @model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.PesquisaViewModel

 ...
```

### 6. Telas que não usem esse *ViewModel* podem chamar a *Partial* sem problemas

Assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_Pesquisa", new PesquisaViewModel())
```

Comment: deixa ver se entendi. Eu crio uma Partial chamada _Pesquisa que pode ser utilizado em várias telas. Ok. Criar a viewModel ok. O item 4, o controller que você se refere é o que eu criar para fazer alguma pesquisa certo? E no item 5, o 'Pesquisa.cshtml é referência ao controller criado anteriormente.

Comment: Se eu criar a 'PesquisaViewModel' como model, ao invés de uma pasta viewModel faz diferença?

Comment: Sobre o 4, sim, é o *Controller* que vai receber a pesquisa. O item 5 é a tela de **resultado** da pesquisa. Pode até chamar de `ResultadoPesquisa.cshtml`, se quiser.

Comment: Melhor você separar *ViewModel* de *Model*. *ViewModels* não são mapeadas em banco.

Comment: Tenho que fazer referência então nos controllers? 'using Minhabase.ViewModel.PesquisaViewModel' ?

Comment: Com certeza tem que.

Answer (score 2):

> Não aconselho utilizar esta forma que irei mostrar, a [resposta do Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102945/20615) expressa uma forma melhor de fazer a busca. Estou postando apenas para fins de conhecimento.

Como o [@CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102945/20615) explicou, não há necessidade de utilizar `POST` para uma busca, você perde a "reutilização" ou até mesmo desvantagem na Otimização para Sites de Busca([SEO](https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls)).

Agora, respondendo sua pergunta, você poderia utilizar `jQuery` ou `javascript` para obter o item selecionado e redirecionar para a página que desejar. Um exemplo seria assim:

```
   $('#pesquisar').click(function () {
            var nivel = $('#NivelId').find(":selected").val();
            location.href = '@Url.Action("Pesquisa","Formacao")?id=' + nivel;
        });
```

Dessa forma você irá obter o valor selecionado e enviar para sua `Action`. Lembrando que se quiser utilizar o filtro apenas ao alterar o valor do `DropDownList`, basta utilizar o [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) no lugar do `.click()`.

Comment: seria só acrescentar esse script dentro da minha view Pesquisa?

Comment: @Victor Sim. teria que retirar o `@html.BeginForm()`