# Filtro de Pesquisa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho uma entidade de Itens que se relaciona com a tabela de produtos e a mesma já esta em produção e esta funcionando perfeitamente! Agora necessito criar um relatório de pesquisa em que o usuário poderá determinar através de filtros as condições desta consulta. Os campos de consulta que o usuário poderá escolher são:

- Data de - Data Pedido De-Até
- Loja
- Item
- Marca
- Forma Pagamento.

O relatório é bem simples e o resultado será exibido através de uma View com List. O relatório já foi criado ***sem a utilização dos campos*** informados anteriormente. Estou utilizando o EntityFramework nas consultas e para este relatório estou atualmente utilizando esta query:

```
return Db.TabCadStatusOrdemServicoItem.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Descricao);
```

A pergunta é: como faço para incluir os campos na consulta acima sabendo que para alguns campos o usuário poderá selecionar a opção todos (ex. loja)?

Grato pela força!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que [esta resposta aqui pode ser útil para você](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102939/guardar-e-enviar-id-de-item-selecionado-no-dropdowlinst/102945#102945).

No seu caso, você pode fazer um *ViewModel* cujos campos sejam `Nullable`:

```
public class ParametrosPesquisaViewModel
{
    public DateTime? DataInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataFinal { get; set; }
    public int? LojaId { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? MarcaId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TabCadStatusOrdemServicoItem> Resultados { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de construção de predicado:

```
        var query = db.TabCadStatusOrdemServicoItem.AsQueryable();
        if (viewModel.DataInicial != null)
        {
            if (viewModel.DataFinal != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(a => a.Data >= viewModel.DataInicial && a.Data <= viewModel.DataFinal);
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.Where(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Data) == viewModel.DataInicial);
            }
        }

        if (viewModel.LojaId != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(a => a.LojaId == (int)viewModel.LojaId);
        }

        // E assim por diante.

         return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Nesta caso Cigano Morrison devo utilizar dois Models na mesma View (ParametrosPesquisaViewModel + TabCadStatusOrdemServicoItem) sendo uma para o filtro e outra para a listagem dos Itens? se sim, não abusando da boa vontade :) - não faço a minima idéia de como implementar duas models na mesma View.

Comment: Bom, então. Na verdade você só passa para a *View* `ParametrosPesquisaViewModel`. A lista de resultados você preenche no *Controller*.

Comment: Blz, a sugestão foi aplicada no meu projeto e deu tudo certo. Obrigado pessoal!!!

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi a pergunta corretamente, você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
var result = Db.TabCadStatusOrdemServicoItem.ToList();

//Para cada campo do filtro, adicionar um bloco If igual ao abaixo
if (!modelFiltro.Foo.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    result = result.Where(x => x.Foo.Equals(modelFiltro.Foo))
}


return result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Descricao);
```

Evidentemente, se o usuário selecionar "Todas" no filtro de lojas, basta você não enviar nenhum Id de loja.

Comment: Eduardo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, vou aplicar a sua dica no meu sistema - Obrigado!