# Como permanecer com o item selecionado em um select após transição de páginas?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, http

Quais são as melhores formas de permanecer com um item selecionado em um select após transição de paginas (Ir para uma página e depois voltar com os campos já selecionados) utilizando ASP.NET MVC? Session? Cache? TempData? Hidden field?

Comment: Depende... tem como explicar mais o seu cenário?

Comment: Eu coloco um filtro em uma página, acesso o detalhe de um item que já está filtrado em uma tabela (Em outra página). Eu tenho a opção de voltar à pagina anterior, mas gostaria que permanecesse com os filtros que já tinha realizado.

Comment: Você pode criar uma Single page application ou guardar tudo isso em algum lugar, acho que no cache da tranquilo

Answer (score 2):

## `GET`

É para isso que a parametrização `GET` foi feita: para que, numa mudança de páginas, os filtros se mantenham.

### Como é o uso disso?

Estou supondo que você tenha um `<form>` em alguma *View* sua:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... }
```

Por padrão, formulários no ASP.NET MVC são `POST`, mas nada impede a gente de usar assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "MeuController", FormMethod.Get)) { ... }
```

Ao submeter seu formulário, você irá notar que os parâmetros preenchidos irão todos para a barra de endereços. Se você recolocar o formulário dentro da tela de resultado de pesquisa, verá que os filtros estarão preenchidos.

[Detalhei tudo isso nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102939/guardar-e-enviar-id-de-item-selecionado-no-dropdowlinst/102945#102945).

Comment: No meu caso, não é um form, são alguns Dropdowns, como ficaria?

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque como estão os *DropDowns*.