# Passagem de parâmetros com Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, terminologia, view

Em `asp.Net MVC`.

Qual a diferença entre usar `ViewBag, ViewData e View Tipada`?

E quando devemos utiliza-las, existe alguma situação especifica?

Existe diferença de performance entre elas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `ViewData`

É um dicionário temporário de valores que serve para passar informações auxiliares entre *Controller* e *View*. Existe apenas durante o processamento da requisição.

É a forma mais rudimentar de passar dados entre *Controller* e *View*. Suas variáveis requerem conversão de tipos para serem usadas. Existe desde a primeira versão do ASP.NET MVC.

## `ViewBag`

Forma semelhante à `ViewData`, mas aproveitando o recurso [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx) introduzido nativamente no .NET 4 em diante. Mais simples de usar, não requer necessariamente conversão para tipos mais complexos.

No .NET, `dynamic` é sempre mais lento, mas a diferença de processamento entre `ViewData` e `ViewBag` é quase imperceptível (a não ser, claro, que você passe um objeto gigantesco por `ViewBag`, o que, além de ser uma má prática, é raro de acontecer).

É a forma que vigora até o MVC5 para passagem de valores acessórios entre *Controller* e *View*.

## View Tipada

Aqui acho que a expressão correta seria "*Model* da *View*", que pode ser na verdade qualquer classe.

Por design, uma *View* só aceita uma classe. Quando duas ou mais classes são necessárias para compor a apresentação, usa-se uma outra classe que contém todas as outras classes, e essa classe que contém as outras é passada para a *View*.

O *Model* da *View* deve conter todas as informações essenciais para compor a apresentação. Em caso de *Views* que modifiquem dados, todos os dados que devem ser modificados através da *View* precisam estar dentro do *Model* da *View*.

Um outro exemplo são telas de formulário de pesquisa, que não exatamente alteram dados, mas precisam firmar um estado de pesquisa entre a aplicação e a *View*. [Explico isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102939/guardar-e-enviar-id-de-item-selecionado-no-dropdowlinst/102945#102945).

## Sobre Usos Recomendados

`ViewData` e `ViewBag` devem ser usadas para, entre outros usos:

- Preencher opções de *DropDowns*;
- Preencher alguma informação de tela que não faz parte dos dados essenciais da *View*;
- Passar alguma mensagem, como por exemplo uma notificação ou um tipo de mensagem de sucesso.

Sobre performance, a tipagem forte sempre prevalece sobre a tipagem dinâmica. Como boa prática, vale sempre a pena converter tudo para tipagem forte, se possível.