# TempData perde propriedade ao usar Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com o seguinte código nas páginas que, para serem acessadas, é necessário realizar o login:

```
if (Session["Login"] == null)
{
    TempData["msg"] = "É necessário realizar o login para acessar esta página!";
    Response.Redirect("/Login/Index");
}
```

Esta `TempData["msg"]` está da seguinte forma na tela de login:

```
@if (TempData["msg"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       @TempData["msg"]
    </div>
}
```

Entretanto a mensagem não está aparecendo, como se o `TempData` estivesse se anulando. O que tenho que fazer para que a mensagem seja passada para a tela de login?

Comment: Para referência: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149665/passagem-de-par%C3%A2metros-com-asp-net-mvc/149674#149674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a `ViewBag` pois ela existe até o final da execução do `response`.

**No controller:**

```
if (Session["Login"] == null)
{
    ViewBag.msg = "É necessário realizar o login para acessar esta página!";
    Response.Redirect("/Login/Index");
}
```

**Na view:**

```
@if (TempData["msg"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       @ViewBag.msg
    </div>
}
```