# redirecionamento de paginas C#/javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Eu estou com uma dúvida um tanto quanto boba ( eu acho ), eu tenho que fazer um filtro para cliente e preciso fazer urgente, então dei um solução "rápida" para meu problema, criei um controler que faz a pesquisa de clientes mas agora com um filtro, e retorna para uma pagina similar a anterior só que com o filtro, o problema e que minha pagina não esta redirecionando corretamente.

Assim esta meu botão pesquisar :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 200px;">
            <input name="ParametroBuscar" id="ParametroBuscar" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Pesquisar" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnPesquisar" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Meu backend esta assim :

```
public ActionResult Pesquisar(string ParametroBuscar)
    {
        int LojistaId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        int lojaId = this.lojaServico.GetMany(l => l.LojistaId == LojistaId).Select(l =>  l.LojaId).FirstOrDefault();




        ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParametroBuscar)){

              List<ClienteLoja> clientes = ClienteLojaServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == lojaId && l.Cliente.Nome != null && l.Cliente.Nome != "" && l.Cliente.Nome.Contains(ParametroBuscar)).ToList();
              clienteModel.Clientes = clientes;
              clienteModel.ParametroBusca = ParametroBuscar;
              clienteModel.LojaId = lojaId;
          }



        return View(clienteModel);
    }
```

E eu criei um javascript assim :

```
  function pesquisarCliente() {
    var parametroPesquisa = {
        'ParametroBuscar': $('#ParametroBuscar').val()
    };
    // lembrando que 'exemplo' será o nome da variavel recebida como parametro, no C#
    $("#disableModal").addClass("disabledbutton");
    $('#loadingModal').show();
    $("#Conteudo").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#btnSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Cliente/Pesquisar", //altere para o caminho que você vai querer mandar o post
        type: "get", //tipo post
        data: parametroPesquisa, //os dados
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.isRedirect) {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Cliente", "Pesquisa", new { ParametroBuscar = "__ParametroBuscar__" })';
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //se deu erro
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);

        }
    });
}
```

Eu fiz um metodo post, o que provavelmente esta errado vendo que o metodo bbackend é `ActionResult`, ele ate entra no metodo e encontra o que eu preciso mas ele não redireciona para a `Pesquisar.cshtml` e não sei como fazer isso. Me parece um coisa bem primaria mas simplesmente não consigo visualizar como ira funcionar, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Guardar e enviar id de item selecionado no dropdowlinst](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102939/guardar-e-enviar-id-de-item-selecionado-no-dropdowlinst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de várias formas:

**Carregando a View com ajax**

Você não precisa alterar seu controller uma vez que ele irá retornar uma View. Altere a chamada ajax para carregar a View com os resultados dentro de uma div ou elemento html:

```
   $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("Pesquisar", "Cliente")',
         data : { ParametroBuscar : $('#ParametroBuscar').val() }
         success: function (html) {
                $('#algumaDiv').html(html);
         }
   });
```

**Utilizar um post**

Isso irá carregar uma nova View, a View com nome Pesquisar, uma vez que você não especificou o nome.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Pesquisar", "Cliente")) 
{
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 200px;">
     <input name="ParametroBuscar" id="ParametroBuscar" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Pesquisar" type="text">
     <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" id="btnPesquisar" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
 </div>
}
```

Altere para HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(string ParametroBuscar)
```