# Código do controlador é executado mas nada acontece

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Depois de muita pesquisa sem resultados venho aqui questionar-vos. O projeto é em `MVC 5` utilizando `C#`.

Este é o código que chama uma controlador MVC

```
$('#btnPesquisa').click(function () {
    var textAPesquisar = $("#txtTermoDePesquisa").val();
    $.ajax({
           url: "/Pensamento/Pesquisar",
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: '{termoAPesquisar:' + JSON.stringify(textAPesquisar) + '}',
           async: false
    });
});
```

Quando faço debug vejo que o controlador recebe o valor  e até me redireciona para o `Home` `Index` e nesse controlador tudo acontece como deve ser, contudo no browser a pagina não muda, fica tudo na mesma.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(string termoAPesquisar)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {query = termoAPesquisar });
}
```

Se eu chamar o `Home` `Index` manualmente, através da barra de endereços do browser, tudo acontece como devia acontecer.

**Como é que é possível que o código seja executado e nada aconteça?**

Comment: Faltou o retorno do `$.ajax`! e também o método está errado ... deveria retornar um json pra tela! Apesar que agora fiquei na dúvida qual é o seu intuito principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este trecho de código realiza uma requisição assíncrona ao seu `Controller`:

```
 $.ajax({
           url: "/Pensamento/Pesquisar",
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: '{termoAPesquisar:' + JSON.stringify(textAPesquisar) + '}',
           async: false
    });
```

E por ser uma requisição assíncrona, seu `Controller` processa esta requisição mas você não está fazendo nada com o seu resultado. Para isto, você precisa adicionar ao código o `callback` responsável por tratar este retorno:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "/Pensamento/Pesquisar",
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: '{termoAPesquisar:' + JSON.stringify(textAPesquisar) + '}',
           async: false,

           success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           }
    });
```

Contudo, acredito que o que você quer na verdade é redirecionar sua página de acordo com o texto digitado no elemento `#txtTermoDePesquisa`. Se este for o caso, atualize a pergunta com o HTML utilizado que eu atualizo a resposta com o que você precisa para isso acontecer sem utilizar ajax.

Segue abaixo uma forma de realizar o post de um formulário para o seu método no controller;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisar", "Pensamento", FormMethod.POST))
{
        <input value="" type="text" name="termoAPesquisar" id="txtTermoDePesquisa" />
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"/>
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Tentei adicionar a callback function como está em cima mas os resultados são os mesmos. O objetivo é pegar no valor introduzido numa caixa de texto que está na barra de navegação, parecido facebook, e enviar para um controlador. O que posso estar a fazer de mal ?

Comment: @Romeu, eu recomendo que você estude bastante o que é ajax, pois irá compreender por que não está atualizando a página. Eu atualizei a resposta com um formulário que realiza uma requisição para seu método no controller utilizando o método POST, que acredito que possa lhe ajudar

Comment: Foi o que fiz, fui estudar e percebi que aquilo que queria fazer não podia ser feito recorrendo ao ajax. Ainda tenho muito que aprender pois não conhecia esse método para postar forms no controlador. Já está a funcionar, muito obrigado.

Comment: Marque a resposta que te ajudou como correta (abaixo dos pontos da mesma), ou responda sua própria pergunta para ajudar àqueles com a mesma dúvida! Boa sorte com os estudos, @Romeu

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo algumas confusões aí.

Primeiro, você está utilizando Ajax para fazer uma busca, até aí normal. Porém, você não está fazendo nada com isso. Como seu retorno é um `RedirectToAction()`, o Ajax não sabe o que deve fazer.

Para seu problema, existe algumas soluções simples, dentre elas apenas um redirec via javascript mesmo (não há necessidade alguma desse Ajax e esse redirect), desta forma:

```
$('#btnPesquisa').click(function () {
    var textAPesquisar = $("#txtTermoDePesquisa").val();
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")?query=' + textAPesquisar;
});
```

Note que o seu POST para `/Pensamento/Pesquisar` não existe mais. Isso porque você não faz nada além do Redirect, então não vejo necessidade dele.

Agora, tem a forma que eu recomentdo de ser feita, que é utilizando um form GET ao invés de javascript. Seria algo parecido com isso:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search" }))
{
    <div>
        <input name="query" value="" type="search" id="txtTermoDePesquisa"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" id="btnPesquisa"/>
    </div>
}
```

Caso queira entender mais sobre o assunto, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102939/20615) possui uma dúvida muito semelhante a sua.

Comment: Obrigado. Tentei usar o redirect via javascript mas também não está a funcionar.. O form GET funcionou mas de uma forma incorreta. O termo de pesquisa é adicionada na barra de endereços, que é o que eu pretendo, mas como o form que recolhe os dados da pesquisa está na barra de navegação, tipo o do facebook, o que me acontecia é que se eu estivesse numa view de LogIn, por exemplo, o termo de pesquisa é adicionado nesse endereço, Fica assim /Acount/LogIn?query=palavraAPesquisar. Ainda não consegui com que ele me redirecione sempre para o /home/index