# Listar tabela com condição ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou estudando ASP.NET MVC5, então fiz um `Model` chamado 'RelatorioTagModels' contendo:

```
 public class RelatorioTagModels
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Vedacao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Fluido { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    public string Criticidade { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public decimal Mtbf { get; set; }
}
```

View do Model `RelatorioTagModels`

```
body>
<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tag)
        </th> 
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fluido)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vedacao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Criticidade)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mtbf)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fluido)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vedacao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Criticidade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mtbf)
        </td>
        <td>              
            @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Index", "RelatorioRa") 
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Por Scaffoding, gerei o `Controller` e as `Views`, onde, ao clicar em `Detalhes`, sou direcionado a outra tabela, onde nesta tabela, gostaria de listar somente os registros que contem a `Tag` do Model `RelatorioTagModels`.

Então criei outro model chamado: `RelatorioRaModels`:

```
  public class RelatorioRaModels
{
    [Key]
    public int RaID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nivel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nº { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Que por Scaffoding, criei o `Controller` e as `Views`

Minha duvida é, como listar no model `RelatorioRaModels` somente os registros da TAG selecionada no model `RelatorioTagModels`

Atualização:

View do model: `RelatorioTagModels`

[image: Primeiro Relatório]

Ao clicar no link `Detalhe` da primeira linha, gostaria de listar somente os registros que pertencem ao TAG nº `P401-1E`, porem, no momento, ele tras a tabela toda.

[image: Segundo Relatório]

Atualização: ActionResult do metodo Detalhar:

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        RelatorioTagModels relatorioTagModels = await db.RelatorioTagModels.FindAsync(id);
        if (relatorioTagModels == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(relatorioTagModels);
    }
```

Atualização:

Ao clicar em detalhar no primeiro relatório (`RelatorioTagModels`) sou direcionado para o `Index` do segundo relatório (`RelatorioRaModels`), onde quero que mostre somente os registros que pertencem aquela TAG.

Ai se eu voltar no primeiro relatório, clicar em detalhes de **outra** TAG, sou direcionado para o segundo relatório, onde preciso que mostre somente os registros da TAG que foi selecionada no primeiro relatório.

é como se eu fizesse um `WHERE` no SQL. Como faço esse `WHERE` ao chamar o index do model `RelatorioRaModels`

Comment: Tipo isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102939/guardar-e-enviar-id-de-item-selecionado-no-dropdowlinst/102945#102945

Comment: Não é bem uma pesquisa, vou melhorar a pergunta, obrigado

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca a `ActionResult` do método de Detalhar.

Comment: Amigo, atualizei a pergunta conforme solicitado

Comment: Eu não entendi por que você salva o relatório em banco.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o primeiro relatorio gerado pelo model RelatorioTagModels é dinamico, o campo MTBF é calculado a partir de uma outra aplicação minha! O segundo relatorio, gerado pelo model RelatorioRaModels tem todas as datas e o numero de cada atualização, e neste segundo relatório (RelatorioRaModels) quero "filtrar", para trazer somente os registros da TAG que foi clicado no primeiro relatorio (RelatorioTagModels) –

Comment: Você quer retornar todos os registros da mesma Tag, como se fosse um `select * from RelatorioTagModels where Tag = 'P401-1E'`?

Comment: @PabloVargas exato amigo, isso mesmo, so que quero utilizar a tabela `RelatorioRaModels`

Comment: Então basicamente o link que o @CiganoMorrisonMendez colocou no primeiro comentário. Mas vou preparar um exemplo e subir no github com seu caso

Comment: Cara, se pudesse fazer isso, me ajudaria muito. mas vou ler de novo o link do Cigano obrigado

Comment: Só para entender, um RelatorioTagModels tem vários RelatorioRaModels?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53846/discussion-between-thomas-erich-pimentel-and-pablo-vargas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, como comentei, o que você precisa é basicamente o que o @Cigano já respondeu aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102945/5846.

Um exemplo que criei para seu caso é o seguinte.

Você irá precisar de uma `ViewModel` para sua pesquisa

```
public class RelatoriosTagsViewModel
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RelatorioTagModels> RelatoriosTags { get; set; }
}
```

Essa `ViewModel` será utilizada na `Index` do `Controller`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(RelatoriosTagsViewModel model)
{    
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new RelatoriosTagsViewModel();
    }

    var query = db.RelatoriosTags.AsQueryable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Tag))
    {
        // cria seu select * from Tag = 'P401-1E', mas somente quando a Tag for preenchida na pesquisa
        query = query.Where(a => a.Tag.Equals(model.Tag));
    }

    model.RelatoriosTags = await query.ToListAsync();

    return View(model);
}
```

Com isso, basta você adicionar um `Form` na `Index.cshtml` com o filtro. Para redirecionar para a lista de `RelatoriosRas` eu adicionei um `ActionLink`, que redireciona para a `Index` do `RelatoriosRasController`.

```
@using RelatoriosTags.ViewModels
@model RelatoriosTagsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RelatoriosTags", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Tags
        </th>
        <th>
            Vedação
        </th>
        <th>
            Fluído
        </th>
        <th>
            Criticidade
        </th>
        <th>
            Mtbf
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.RelatoriosTags)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(linkText: item.Tag, actionName: "Index", controllerName: "RelatoriosRas", routeValues: new { tagId = item.TagID }, htmlAttributes: new { })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vedacao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fluido)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Criticidade)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mtbf)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TagID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TagID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TagID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Já a `Index` do `RelatoriosRasController` fica da seguinte forma

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? tagId)
{
    var relatorioRaModels = db.RelatoriosRas.Include(r => r.RelatorioTag);

    if (tagId.HasValue)
    {
        //realiza o filtro para a tag selecionada
        relatorioRaModels = relatorioRaModels.Where(a => a.TagID == tagId);
    }

    return View(await relatorioRaModels.ToListAsync());
}
```

O `Index.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<RelatoriosTags.Models.RelatorioRaModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RelatorioTag.Tag)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Data)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nivel)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nº)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatorioTag.Tag)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nivel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nº)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.RaID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.RaID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.RaID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Mas eu fiz uma alteração na sua modelagem, criando uma relação entre seus dois Models.

No `RelatorioTagModels` eu adicionei

```
public ICollection<RelatorioRaModels> RelatoriosRas { get; set; }
```

No `RelatorioRaModels` eu alterei

```
//[Required]
//public string Tag { get; set; }

public int TagID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TagID")]
public virtual RelatorioTagModels RelatorioTag { get; set; }
```

O código completo do exemplo você pode ver no [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/RelatoriosTags)

Answer (score 1):

O erro tá no link de Detalhar.

Repare que no seu `Controller` você espera um "id" - que você também permite ser `null` ao declará-lo como `nullable`.

Caso o `id` não seja permitido ser `null`, que aparentemente é o caso, você precisa esperar somente um tipo `int`..e não `int?`.

A modificação principal vem aqui:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Index", "RelatorioRa", new { id = item.TagID })
```

Dessa forma você irá passar o `id` como parâmetro `GET`.

E também retiraria o `nullable` da `Controller`:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    var relatorioTagModels = await db.RelatorioTagModels.FindAsync(id);

    if (relatorioTagModels == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(relatorioTagModels);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, não é bem isso, veja, eu quero pegar a TAG do primeiro relatório gerado pelo model `RelatorioTagModels` e que ao clicar em detalhes, ele me direcione para o ìndex` do model ´RelatorioRaModels`, mostrando somente os registros da TAG do primeiro relatório.